# how to check if PyQt window exists

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have an application in development using PyQt4.

This app will popup a window on particular events in the application.

I want to know if the popup window which was popped up exists on the next event i wan to display the message on the same window rather tan creating another window.

For example you can consider a messaging application. where when we get a message the window will popup. and if we receive the message again from same user the message will be appended to that window itself.

My scenario is also the same.

Anyone have any idea on this...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is keep a reference to the popup window and then reset the text as necessary.

Here's a simple demo:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('ShowTime!', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self._dialog = None

    def handleButton(self):
        if self._dialog is None:
            self._dialog = QtGui.QMessageBox(self)
            self._dialog.setWindowTitle('Messages')
            self._dialog.setModal(False)
            pos = self.pos()
            pos.setX(pos.x() + self.width() + 10)
            self._dialog.move(pos)
        self._dialog.setText(
            'The time is: %s' % QtCore.QTime.currentTime().toString())
        self._dialog.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```